# Variadic function dosen't accept string objects

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Reading about variadic functions, I found a `sum` function which accepts any number of any numeric type and calculate sum of them.

Having templated nature of this function, I expected it accepts `string` objects since operator `+` is defined for strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T sum(T && x)
{
    return std::forward<T>(x);
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
typename std::common_type<T, Args...>::type sum(T && x, Args &&... args)
{
    return std::forward<T>(x) + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto y = sum(1, 2, 4.5); // OK
    cout << y << endl;

    auto x = sum("Hello!", "World"); // Makes error
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> invalid operands of types 'const char [7]' and 'const char [6]' to
>   binary 'operator+'

I expected it concatenates  `Hello!` and `World` and prints out `Hello!World`.
What is the problem?

Comment: `const char*` doesn't have overloaded `operator+`, like it says in the error. Pretty clear if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are not `std::string` objects. No `operator +` is defined for arrays of characters.

As your compiler is telling you, `"Hello!"` has type `const char[7]`, while `"World"` has type `const char[6]`. Try declaring two variables of those types and taking their sum:

```
int main()
{
    char const a[7] = "Hello!";
    char const b[6] = "World";
    (a + b);
}
```

And the compiler will show you a similar error:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char [7]' and 
       'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'
```

To make your code work, wrap at least one of the two string literals into an `std::string` object (two corresponding overloads of `operator +` exist for `std::string` objects):

```
auto x = sum(std::string("Hello!") + "World");
```

or:

```
auto x = sum("Hello!" + std::string("World"));
```

Of course, you can also wrap both arguments, but that's unnecessary.

Comment: `auto x = sum(string("Hello!"), string("World"));` !

Comment: @MM.: Yes. That's because you wrap the literals in `string` objects

Comment: It's better I go sleep before asking worse questions!

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem isn't with variadic templates, but with your expectations - string literals, like `"hello"` are not of type `std::string`. They're of type `char const[N]` where `N` is the number of characters + 1. If you actually construct a string from them (or even just from the first one), it works as expected:

```
// snip

int main()
{
    auto y = sum(1, 2, 4.5); // OK
    cout << y << endl;

    auto x = sum(std::string("Hello!"), "World"); // OK
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/GO0psn)